# More <item> tags in a <item> in RSS

Tags: xml, rss

In a RSS item I need to have more item. How could I do?

```
<item>
  <title> </title>
  ...
  <item>
     <title </title>
     ....
  </item>
  <item>
     <title </title>
     ....
  </item>
</item>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to add several items within another item--the point of RSS is that it should be "Really Simple Syndication" so that it is easy to parse and translate.

One alternative is to use a unique `<category>` for each of the items in that group, with the group title as the category name.

Another option is to use the `<link>` tag to add a link to a webpage, where the webpage consists of the items in some form of a list. This option is complicated and not recommended unless you are planning on using the information in the RSS feed in some other form such as displaying it on a webpage anyways.